# Python matplotlib import isn't working: DLL load failed while importing _path

Tags: python, matplotlib, importerror

I installed matplotlib with `pip install matplotlib`. When i try to import the module this comes up.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Code\Python\matlibb\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib as mpl
  File "C:\Users\Acer A517\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    from . import _api, cbook, docstring, rcsetup
  File "C:\Users\Acer A517\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 26, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like
  File "C:\Users\Acer A517\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py", line 82, in <module>
    from matplotlib import _api, cbook, scale
  File "C:\Users\Acer A517\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\scale.py", line 18, in <module>
    from matplotlib.ticker import (
  File "C:\Users\Acer A517\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\ticker.py", line 179, in <module>
    from matplotlib import transforms as mtransforms
  File "C:\Users\Acer A517\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 46, in <module>
    from matplotlib._path import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _path: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
```

Translation of last sentence: "The specified module was not found"

I tried reinstalling matplotlib but it didnt work.

Comment: I see several other questions about this specific bug.  If I understand the issue correctly, it seems that that matplotlib module is linked against some DLLs that are either missing or incompatible on some systems, though I don't have a Windows machine readily available at the moment where I could check exactly what the issue is.

Comment: There is also an issue about it here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/18292  Indeed, I think the solution on the linked question, concerning installing the correct VC runtime redistributable should work.

Comment: installing the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable worked perfectly, thank you for your help